# #<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

Gone through a lot of answers but still couldn't find the solution.
I have been trying to get a successful response for a POST request to the following controller,

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

if @user.save
  render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
else
  render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end


private
 def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :password)
end
end
```

Although I send all the parameters mentioned,in the request,I am still facing the error.

```
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "#<ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user>"
```

I am using rails version `5.2.1`

Comment: Could you share the View's code or data being sent in the post request?

Comment: { "user": { "name": "pranesh", "email": "pranesh@gmail.com", "phone":"987654321","password": "hello" } }

This is the data sent in POST request

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the logs, what does the data transferred in your post request look like?

When you get that type of error, often it's because you send the data like this:

```
{ first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', ...}
```

When the server expects you to nest this into a `user` object (hence the `require(:user) in your strong_params`:

```
{ user: { first_name: 'John', ... } }
```

Comment: { "user": { "name": "pranesh", "email": "pranesh@gmail.com", "phone":"987654321","password": "hello" } } 
This is the data sent in POST request

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me.
I made just only one hash in params method instead of nested hash.
my user_params method was:-

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:name, :email, :phone, :password)
end
```

OR You can use your method but your parameter passed in user hash like below.

```
{user: {name: "bittu", email: "abc@yopmail.com", phone: 123456, password: "123456"  } }
```