# ActionController::ParameterMissing while trying to POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a simple email signup form that for now only accepts your email. However, if I try to post, I get the following error message

```
Started POST "/landing" for 127.0.0.1 
Processing by LandingController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "txtEmail"=>"sometestemail", "commit"=>"Save "}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 821)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: signup):

app/controllers/landing_controller.rb:22:in `signup_params'
app/controllers/landing_controller.rb:10:in `create'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 
Processing by LandingController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering landing/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered landing/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.6ms | Allocations: 2752)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 3.0ms | Allocations: 5456)
Completed 200 OK
```

According to these StackOverflow questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845593/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-us) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034096/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-acco), the problem is that while I'm passing `{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "txtEmail"=>"sometestemail", "commit"=>"Save "}`, the controller expects `{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "signup" = {"txtEmail"=>"sometestemail"}, "commit"=>"Save "}`

And so I have 2 choices. I can either change the controller from `params.require(:signup).permit(:txtEmail)` to `params.permit(:txtEmail)`, or I can find some way to wrap my POST data.

Indeed, altering the controller does work, and I can get txtEmail on my Signups table and display them from signup_controller's `def show`. However, I also get the following error during POST

```
Unpermitted parameters: :authenticity_token, :commit. Context: { controller: LandingController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007f1e4cd43f48>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "txtEmail"=>"sometestemail", "commit"=>"Save ", "controller"=>"landing", "action"=>"create"} }
```

For data protection regulation reasons, I intend to use SSL on this web app, and I'm afraid this error will introduce problems with SSL.

So I have the following questions.

1. Can I just use the fix I just mentioned (removing `.require(:signup)`) without compromising SSL?
2. If not, how can I fix this?

**landing_controller.rb**

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

  def create
    @signup = Signup.new(signup_params)

    if @signup.save
      redirect_to @signup
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
  def signup_params
    params.require(:signup).permit(:txtEmail)
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with signup: @signup do |form| %>
<div>
    <%= form.text_area :txtEmail %><br>
    <% @signup.errors.full_messages_for(:txtEmail).each do |message| %>
    <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= form.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :landing, :only => [:index, :new, :create]
  resources :signup, :only => [:show]
  root "landing#index"
end
```

There is no custom JS involved.

Comment: `form_with signup: @signup` should be `form_with model: @signup`

Comment: That gives creates a rendering error ```undefined method `signups_path' ... Did you mean?  signup_path```

Comment: please add your routes for signup to your question

Comment: I added routes.rb to the question. Also, I solved the problem by moving the form to ```def new``` instead of using ```def index```, and using ```redirect_to({action: "new"})```. It appears Rails just wasn't designed to take input from the index page.

Comment: Rails really likes conventions.